# Detecting jQuery element; delete if found, create if not

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to detect if an element exists, if it does it needs to be deleted, if it doesn't it needs to be created

```
if ( $('#fooEle').length )
    $('#fooEle').remove();
} else {
    $('<div/>', { id: 'fooEle' }).appendTo('#fooEleParent');
};
```

I'm getting Unexpected identifier error on the `else` part of this...
the line works on its own when not enclosed in `if` statement...

Comment: You are missing starting brace after if `if ( $('#fooEle').length ) {`

Comment: missing a `{` after `if`.... there are numerous linting services online you can use...as well as integrated linters in IDE's. SHouldn't be posting simple sytax problems here

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about syntax error

Comment: lol, it's been a long day. I deserved that -1

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED:

```
if ( $('#fooEle').length ) {
    $('#fooEle').remove();
} else {
    $('<div/>', { id: 'fooEle' }).appendTo('#fooEleParent');
};
```

Comment: that is not the same as using OP `if`

Comment: it's sort of a switch function called in the same manner on "enter" and "exit" of a site section. it needs to detect to do proper thing. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It's not the same. I will correct that.